# An issue about the description of virtual function in the standard

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, language-lawyer, virtual-functions

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct A { 
    virtual void f(){
        std::cout<<"1\n";
    } 
};
struct B : A {

};
struct C : A { 
    void f(){
        std::cout<<"abc\n";
    } 
};
struct D : B, C { 

}; 
int main(){
  D mostDerived{};
  D* ptr = &mostDerived;
  B* bptr = ptr;
  A* aptr = bptr;
  aptr->f();
}
```

Consider the above code , the [outcome](https://godbolt.org/z/7bMKfW) is `1`. However , I have doubt to this outcome due to what the standard says:
[class.virtual#def:final_overrider](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.virtual#def:final_overrider)

> For convenience we say that any virtual function overrides itself. A virtual member function C​::​vf of **a class object S** is a final overrider unless **the most derived class of which S is a base class subobject** (if any) declares or **inherits another member function that overrides vf**.

[class.derived#def:inheritance](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.derived#def:inheritance)

> Members of a base class other than constructors are said to be inherited by the derived class. Constructors of a base class can also be inherited as described in [namespace.udecl].

IIUC,  consider the base class subobject of type `A` in B and in `C` as `A1`, `A2` respectively. In my example, the most derived class is `D`, According to the above rules, for class `B`, the final overrider is `A::f` which is inherits from `A`, for class `C`, the final overrider is `C::f` which is declared in class `C`, and for class `D`, it's derived from `B` and `C`, so it will inherit these members from `B` and `C`. Since `C::f` overrides `A::f`, So according to the rule `unless **the most derived class of which S is a base class subobject** (if any) declares or **inherits another member function that overrides vf**`, where consider the `A1` as `S`(namely, `A1` is the subobject of class `D`), where `D` inherits the `another member function that overrides vf` which is `C::f`. that means, the final override for the subobject `A1` should be `C::f`, hence , I wonder why the outcome wasn't `abc` instead for `1`?

Another question is:

```cpp
struct A { 
    virtual void f(){
        std::cout<<"1\n";
    } 
};
struct B : A {
  void f(){}
};
struct C : A { 
    void f(){}
};
struct D : B, C { 

};
```

Both `B::f` and `C::f` override the virtual function `A::f`, but they do not override each other, so which the function does `D` inherits? or both are inherited by `D`?

If I miss something, how to read the above rule correctly. Or for the first question, Is the above rule indeed unclear to make misunderstanding?

Comment: please one question per question

Comment: @idclev463035818 I think they would be the same question, namly  how does `inherit` perform in virtual function rules.

Comment: Inheritance and overriding are things that were always understood intuitively by programmers as well as implementers, rather than properly described with readable text and proper terminology. Unless it was fixed recently I think even the description of a base is defective, as in arbitrary MI supporting languages like C++, a base subobject must be described by a path. *A base subobject is not a type!*

Comment: @curiousguy I don't agree. Maybe programmers could understand what is final overrider according to his intuitive, however implements should implement final overrider according to this specification. AFAIN, the current wording is very vague for describing what's the actually final overrider for each base subobject.

Comment: @jackX You are very wrong. Implementers don't follow spec, they follow knowledge and intuition. That's a fact. I know that. I've been there (std committee) and nobody would agree w/ you off record. Hopefully implementers don't follow the pathetic attempt at writing spec because neither C not C++ committee has the expertise nor organization not discipline to wrong one.

Comment: @curiousguy I really agree with "Implementers don't follow spec". AFAIN, sometimes, what the spec expects the implementation do this things, but `GCC` and `Clang` do other things, that is, the spec says that the code is well-formed, gcc and clang do not agree, and say that code is ill-formed. Many times, I test these codes through these compilers to examine the relevant sections, even the example in this section.

Answer (score 2):

> > ... A virtual member function C​::​vf of a class object S is a final overrider unless the most derived class of which S is a base class subobject (if any) declares or inherits another member function that overrides vf.

The quoted rule might be defective by being a bit misleading.

It should not be sufficient for `vf` to be overridden for just *any* base of type `B`, but it should be overridden specifically for *that base subobject*. In your example, there are two base sub objects of type `A`, one of which has `A::f` overridden and the other does not.

> so which the function does D inherits? or both are inherited by D?

Both are inherited.

Comment: I think so. Maybe change the wording to `unless the most derived class of which S is a base class subobject (if any) declares that function or inherits another member function from the subobject  that contains S overrides vf.`, if `S` here refers to the class where the virtual function is first declared.

Comment: It is was me, the whole "inherited member" stuff would go away. I just don't find a use for the inheritance concept for specification purpose. You can describe inheritance (or rather, derivation) w/o using "inherited member". We just need "lookup".

Comment: @curiousguy. Yes,  "inherited member" may make a bit misleading for some other rules, just "member names lookup" is sufficient to describe how these members of base classes are inherited by derived class.

Comment: @jackX My beef is w/ the metaphor "inheritance". When you inherit you pay taxes then it's your, period. You can't have "access control" to a good that you inherited. *Usually* inherited stuff is directly accessible not mediated, through a proxy, etc. It's just 1) misleading 2) unnecessary for beginners.

Comment: @curiousguy I prefer to use such wording "directed acyclic graph of base classes" to describe the procedure of overriding virtual function, each later derived class in which such a function is declared will override that of previous base class in this graph, otherwise the later derived class "inherited" such a function,  and the final overrider is applied to the **subobject** in this chain.